# Applying for a German visa in Russia as a non-resident

Tags: visas, germany, russia, study

i am a student in russia, (non-russian nationality), i want apply for a German language visa (national visa D) in the German embassy in russia to study in germany after finishing my study here(to not lose time), without going back to my home country .
My question is :
Can the german embassy deny my application because i am non Russian citizen? [Like... it will be more hard to get the visa D if i don't apply in my home country].
Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be that you must make it plausible that you will leave Germany again. If you cannot or don't want to return to Russia, you would have to explain clearly and convincingly why you would return to your home country after stays in Russia and Germany.